# Can strict positive square matrix contain non zero same eigenvalues

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Can someone give an example of a strict positive square matrix that contains non zero same eigenvalues?
In another word, a positive square matrix with repeated positive eigenvalues (algebraic multiplicity equals to at least two). Or such matrix doesn't exist? Thanks in advance.

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, isn't any diagonal matrix with a fixed positive integer as all its diagonal entries will do ?